# Taking the mean of a sum in a time period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code which as current, takes the mean number of people per visit per week.

```
df = information.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean('people')
```

How would I change this so as instead of taking the mean number per visit, I take the average number of visitors a day in each week.

Example df

```
   date                 people
2012-01-02 20:00:00       x
2012-01-02 20:00:00       x
2012-01-03 16:00:00       x
2012-01-03 10:00:00       x
2012-01-03 20:00:00       x
2012-01-04 20:00:00       x
...
```

And I want a df output resembling

```
   week       avergeperday
2012-01-02         x
2012-01-09         x
2012-01-16         x
2012-01-23         x
2012-01-30         x
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two groupby:

```
(information.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).size()
            .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean()
)
```

Or if `people` is the number of people coming in at that time:

```
(information.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['people'].sum()
            .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean()
)
```